# Get the data value from an object using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am passing data to a server using a jQuery function.

```
data : {"id" : "3"}
```

How can I get the `3` value from the object? Suppose I can access `data` and it outputs `{"id" : "3"}` I have tried 2 methods but neither works.

**Method 1:**

I tried to get the values using:

```
$(this)[0].data.id
```

**Result:** `undefined`

**Method 2:**

```
JSON.parse($(this)[0].data).id
```

**Result:** `Unexpected token`

---

Printing  to the console looks like:

```
[Object]
0
:
Object
accepts
:
Object
async
:
true
contentType
:
"application/json; charset=utf-8"
contents
:
Object
converters
:
Object
crossDomain
:
false
data
:
"{ 'id': '3' }"
dataType
:
"json"
dataTypes
:
Array[2]
error
:
(uploadifyDiv, response, a, b)
flatOptions
:
Object
global
:
true
hasContent
:
true
isLocal
:
false
jsonp
:
"callback"
jsonpCallback
:
()
processData
:
true
responseFields
:
Object
success
:
(response)
type
:
"POST"
url
:
"/TestApp/Pages/Uploadify.aspx/FileUploaded"
xhr
:
ci()
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Object[0]
```

Comment: Do you mean `data.id`?

Comment: Try this `data["id"]`?

Comment: @AlonEitan it's not working...

Comment: @Anonymous You've shown us a partial object - `data` is a member of another object that is not presented in the question. Can you please add the rest of the object (Unless @mmm's answer helped you)

Comment: @AlonEitan update question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it by `data.id`.

```
console.log(data.id);
```

If it is stringified, you need to parse it first:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data.id);
```

Or as @Alon has commented, it might be a object within another object. In this case, do

```
 console.log(parentObj.data.id);
```